# ReadWriteLocks-(Non-reentrant) how it supports multiple readers to acquire read locks

Tags: java, multithreading, readwritelock

I came across below non-reentrant implementation of ReadWriteLock in many tutorials.

```
public class ReadWriteLock{

    private int readers       = 0;
    private int writers       = 0;
    private int writeRequests = 0;

    public synchronized void lockRead() throws InterruptedException{
      while(writers > 0 || writeRequests > 0){
        wait();
      }
    readers++;
    }

    public synchronized void unlockRead(){
      readers--;
      notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void lockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
      writeRequests++;

      while(readers > 0 || writers > 0){
        wait();
      }
      writeRequests--;
      writers++;
    }

    public synchronized void unlockWrite() throws InterruptedException{
      writers--;
      notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Question:

An object(say `lock`) of this class is shared across all reader and writer threads for synchronization.

Lets assume that Reader T1 calls `lock.lockRead()`, this acquires the lock on the lock object, and Reader T2 at the same time calls `lockRead()` on the same object. But T1 already has locked the object, so T2 should be blocked and waiting in the Queue.

So, how does the code allow multiple readers to set readLock at the same time?

Please correct me know when I got this wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that no 2 threads can concurrently execute the *body* of the `lockRead()` method. But that's not necessary for the reader/writer pattern to work correctly and with the expected performance.

What matters is that the `lockRead()` method returns quickly if there are no active writers (`wait` is not invoked). The lock is released when the method ends, thus allowing another thread to acquire a read lock as well.

So, yes, the act of acquiring of a read lock (incrementing `readers`) is serialized. But it happens so quickly, that it works just fine.

To illustrate:

```
private ReadWriteLock lock = new ReadWriteLock(); // this instance is shared by all threads

public void ReadSomething() {
    try {
        lock.lockRead(); // serialized, but very quick

        PerformWork(); // potentially slower, but is concurrent
    } finally {
        lock.unlockRead(); // serialized, but very quick
    }
}
```

If 2 threads try to run the above `ReadSomething()` method at the exact same time, it's true that only one thread will be able to execute `lock.lockRead()` at a time.  But as soon as that method returns for one of the threads, the second thread will be able to execute it as well. And the call to `lock.lockRead()` happens so quickly, that you won't even be able to notice that one thread was waiting for the other.

What matters is that both threads are then able to execute the more time consuming `PerformWork()` at the same time.

Comment: Thanks ,that was helpful